# Negative look behind with variable length match before it

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to extract a lone # on the end of addresses, but only if not after certain designations.

Here is the regex I am testing:

```
/(?<!apt|appt|appartment|ste|suite|box)[,.]? ?# ?([0-9]+)$/i
```

The regex should fail in this case:

```
123 W Somewhere St Apt # 321
```

The regex should find a match in this:

```
123 W Somewhere St # 321
```

However, it matches both of the above.

I found that if I change `[,.]? ?# ?` to simply `#` then it works.

However, that means that simply removing a space or adding a period to the address will throw it off.

How do I get my negative look-behind to work and allow my regex to remain flexible in this instance?

Implemented in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a lookbehind in this situation (with optional content after), but you can use this alternative:

```
/(?!\b(?:apt|appt|appartment|ste|suite|box))\b\w+[,.]? ?# ?\K[0-9]+/i
```

`\K` reset all the match before.

Comment: That works, but doesn't allow me to replace the # sign when I use it in preg_replace().

Comment: @EcomEvo: Just move the `\K` before the `#`